# multiple significance testing of large data

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I am doing analysis using multiple significance testing between about 20 parameters of data with >8000 rows. Since the number is reasonably large, even minor differences are coming with highly significant P values. For example difference, in weight of persons in 2 groups: 65.6 vs 65.8 kg, p-value < 2.2e-16. How does one tackle this kind of situation?

Comment: If you're testing significance (and actually believing the p-values), you're not doing EDA!

Comment: As you have found, that's not a profitable avenue of investigation: you have enough data to discern potentially *nonlinear* relationships among the data. What do your scatterplot matrices suggest?

Comment: I am getting a seasonal variation (plot with values on y-axis and month on x-axis) with lower values in summer months. In some there is a linear relationship while in most there is random scatter.

Answer (score 3):

another, perhaps complementary approach is to report effect size, % change and its purpoted biological significance alongside any p-value. You could also reformulate your hypothesis to be more precise, rather than just testing for *any* effect.

Comment: I would categorise on effect size, eg fix sig level and  identify variables that had 10% diff, 20%  diff etc

Answer (score 1):

A very common approach to this situation is to use a [Lasso Regression](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html).  This type of regression optimizes the complexity and accuracy of a model, allowing an analyst to understand which variables are useful for prediction. Essentially, the procedure is to include all the independent variables in a single regression model and the Lasso will select the few most important variables.

[This link](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) has some very helpful examples to get you started.