# Is chi square test too strict?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

Below is the **histogram** and the **model distribution** which goodness-of fit that I want to test

[image]

Judging by the eye, I would say this is a pretty good fit.

However, when I run the `chi square` test, it fails. The data for `observed count`, and `expected count` is as follows:

```
0   903 1730    2637
2937    3678    3539    3870
3353    3406    2810    2843
2098    2051    1577    1426
982 873 601 521
385 342 232 197
127 104 57  52
23  16  17  10
7   6       

0.00    847.25  1707.92     2512.40 
3131.78     3484.96     3600.03     3565.79 
3449.83     3272.62     3033.35     2737.29 
2402.19     2051.91     1709.04     1390.81 
1107.99     865.54  663.95  500.70 
371.55  271.49  195.43  138.64 
96.95   66.83   45.41   30.42 
20.08   13.06   8.36    5.27 
3.28    2.00
```

By calculation, `chi square statistics` is 284. On the loosest standard, a `chi square(34)` with `1 - a = 0.95` is 48.6

Since `284 > 48.6`, the distribution should be rejected.

Really? Or Did I made any mistake?

I take a rough calculation, for `48.6/34 = 1.3`, which is the average of accepting level of variance. However, take an example for the 3rd bin, `(2637-2512)^2 = 15625`,  which is **6 times of the expected frequency, 2512**. Is it too strict?

Possible useful links:

[sample size too large?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125750/sample-size-too-large?lq=1)

[Are large data sets inappropriate for hypothesis testing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/are-large-data-sets-inappropriate-for-hypothesis-testing?lq=1)

Comment: *My* eye says the fit and the data are clearly different.  And therein lies the utility of formal hypothesis tests: they help remove the subjective, undocumentable, and irreproducible differences that can arise among multiple opinions. If the test is appropriate for the data, then the result is indisputable. What you should instead be asking is whether the *size* of the difference it detects is of any concern.

Comment: @whuber, in my case, I think the difference between the model and the histogram is acceptable (I understand that the data retrive process would introduce a lot of variance like this). And It's totally OK to be rejected for some gof test. The problem is that, there is `some fit` here, and I don't know if there is other good way of measuring it and expressing it. I have `R square`, but it's too insensitve, while `chi square` is too sensitive.

Comment: Sensitivity is a *good* thing when it comes to measuring fits.  Regardless, how you measure the goodness of fit ought to depend on what you're attempting to accomplish.  As an example, if it is crucial in an application to model the largest values accurately, then the goodness of fit measurement ought to weight the upper tail of the distribution more heavily than the rest.  I hope it's clear that these considerations are independent of, and separate from, whether the differences may be statistically "significant."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a well-known fact that frequentist hypothesis tests can reject the null hypothesis due to differences that are of extremely small size, if the sample size is large enough. In your case the match of the data with the theoretical distribution indeed seems reasonably good,  but your sample size is also extremely large. In some cases such a rejection of the null hypothesis may be irrelevant (e.g. if there is only a small deviation of residuals from normality for a linear regression model) and sometimes this is what one is looking for.

Comment: Then is there any other approach that I can turn to? I may try `K-S` test instead. Or any approach that I can `quantify` the certainty of goodness? `Chi square` may be too strict for my case, and I don't know how can I make it `looser`.

Comment: @cqcn1991, you need to distinguish between statistical significance and subject-matter significance. See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108911/why-does-frequentist-hypothesis-testing-become-biased-towards-rejecting-the-null/151415#151415) excellent thread. $\chi^2$ test is fine in what it addresses (statistical significance) and I suspect K-S should not differ from it too much.

Comment: @cqcn1991 The chi-square is one of the *lowest* power goodness of fit tests in common use. Any decent test of goodness of fit would reject much more often. The KS is not high power but it leaves the chi-square in the dust.

Comment: The alternative is what you have already done, plot and see if it fits. If you need a fancy name for it, you can call it the interoccular trauma test (does it hit you between the eyes test).

Comment: @MaartenBuis, Well... I need an indicator to improve my model fitting. I formerly do it by `R square` and `square error`, but they are not good enough, and that's one of reasons I want a goodness-of-fit test.

Comment: With an indicator you try to quantify the difference between your theoretical and observed data. Both R2 and all the goodness of fit tests do that. The problem is which cut-off-value do you choose. Statistical tests have very particular way of choosing the cut-off point, which is typically not what you want in large datasets. They are not wrong, they just answer a different questions than the one you are interested in. The interoccular trauma test is a good alternative. However, if you want to automate that you need to find some other value, which will always be arbitrary.